# Replace values in list - Python

Tags: python, list, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor the following code:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
labels[0] = labels[0].replace(' ', '_')
labels[1] = labels[1].replace(' ', '_')
labels[2] = labels[2].replace(' ', '_')
labels[3] = labels[3].replace(' ', '_')
labels[5] = labels[5].replace(' ', '_')
labels[6] = labels[6].replace(' ', '_')
df.columns = labels

df.head()
```

The try to refactor code is bellow:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
n=0
for n in list(df.columns):
    labels[n].replace(' ','_')
    n = n+1

df.columns = labels
df.head()
```

But I'm receiving the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-63763510d35a> in <module>()
      2 n=0
      3 for n in list(df.columns):
----> 4     labels[n].replace(' ','_')
      5     n = n+1
      6 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mix and match two different types of iteration (index-based and value-based).  You can do this much more simply as a list comprehension, iterating over the values and building a new list out of the replacements:

```
df.columns = [n.replace(' ', '_') for n in list(df.columns)]
```

If you were to do it by iterating over the indices of the list to modify each element in place, that would look like:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
for n in range(len(labels)):
    labels[n] = labels[n].replace(' ','_')
df.columns = labels
```

Incrementing `n` is not necessary because the `for...in range` already gives you increasing values of `n`.  You'd only need to manage the value of `n` yourself if you were  writing a `while` loop:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
n = 0
while n < len(labels):
    labels[n] = labels[n].replace(' ','_')
    n = n + 1
df.columns = labels
```

The first method (the list comprehension) is what I would recommend.